# What is gatsbyjs’ release strategy

Tags: javascript, npm, gatsby

Could someone please talk about or link me to the justification behind the package publishing strategy? I would like to know why there are so many “version bump only” releases, it makes changelogs overly verbose and => hard to upgrade packages in a timely way. It also makes version diffing harder.

e.g. https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/master/packages/gatsby/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: It seems like the "version bump only" releases actually change the versions of the dependencies, making that package act a bit like a meta-package. So you *do* effectively get code changes via those releases, the code changes just happen to be "hidden" in the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

The [justification behind the package publishing strategy](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md):

> Gatsby is distributed as a monorepo using lerna. Several other large open-source projects are distributed this way, including babel, react, etc.
>
> This means that our CHANGELOG.md files are distributed alongside the package itself in the packages directory.

[Lerna](https://github.com/lerna/lerna) helps "Splitting up large codebases into separate independently versioned packages". Since Gatsby is an open source project with many different plugins, themes, core, etc. this kind of philosophy leads to many incremental updates across many packages. Therefore fast iteration with an open source community is possible:

> Splitting up large codebases into separate independently versioned packages is extremely useful for code sharing. However, making changes across many repositories is messy and difficult to track, and testing across repositories gets complicated really fast.
>
> To solve these (and many other) problems, some projects will organize their codebases into multi-package repositories (sometimes called monorepos). Projects like Babel, React, Angular, Ember, Meteor, Jest, and many others develop all of their packages within a single repository.
>
> Lerna is a tool that optimizes the workflow around managing multi-package repositories with git and npm.
>
> Lerna can also reduce the time and space requirements for numerous copies of packages in development and build environments - normally a downside of dividing a project into many separate NPM packages. See the hoist documentation for details.

Comment: I have worked with Lerna before but I do not remember having to cut releases for every single package in the monorepo. Perhaps my memory is askew but I thought you could just cut a release for a package if and only if the code in that package had changed. Joachim’s comment above makes more sense though and is more of an answer, I had already read this documentation. I wanted to know where all the “version bump only” releases were coming from.

Comment: @JaKXz: sounds like gatsby uses [independent mode](https://github.com/lerna/lerna#independent-mode) and you're used to fixed mode.